# An R function to ensure existing matrix rows are not overwrittern using rbind?

Tags: r, loops, rbind, write.table

I am trying to create a loop using for statements that adds the name of the variable that is analysed by a statistical test (wilcoxon.test) to the left of all associated test statistics in a single row of a dataframe.

I have found the code excluding the second 'for' statement containing the 'i' reference to work fine - so the statistics are correct, but when I add the code in (incuding the for statement referencing the 'i' and also listing the 'i' under the vector specified under 'rbind' all of the previously correct statistics are overwritten with a set of statistical results from a single test.

```
dta <- c()
max_col_A1.1_OR_df_transp <- ncol(A1.1_OR_df_transp)

  for(j in 2:ncol(numeric_A1.1_OR_df_transp)){ 
  for(i in colnames(A1.1_OR_df_transp[2:max_col_A1.1_OR_df_transp])){
  wilcoxon_input <- as.matrix(c(A1.1_OR_df_transp[1:23,j], A1.1_OR_df_transp[24:76,j]))
  wilcoxon_result <- wilcox.test(wilcoxon_input[1:23], wilcoxon_input[24:76], alternative = "two.sided", paired = FALSE, exact = TRUE)
    dta <- rbind(dta,c(i,(unlist( wilcoxon_result))))
  }
}
```

Expected Results should look like (A):

```
head(dta)

[1,] "AAA_8.44_753.9742mz"  "1214"      "2.2272910427744e-18"  "0"                       
"two.sided" "Wilcoxon rank sum test"                            
"wilcoxon_input[1:23] and wilcoxon_input[24:76]"
[2,] "AAA_9.03_190.0498mz"  "1059"      "2.02343356121504e-08" "0"                       
"two.sided" "Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction" 
"wilcoxon_input[1:23] and wilcoxon_input[24:76]"
```

Actual results (B): (notice how the variable name (far left is correct) but, the other test results are being copied)

```
head(dta)

[1,] "AAA_8.44_753.9742mz"  "1214"      "2.2272910427744e-18" "0"                       
"two.sided" "Wilcoxon rank sum test" "wilcoxon_input[1:23] and 
wilcoxon_input[24:76]"
[2,] "AAA_9.03_190.0498mz"  "1214"      "2.2272910427744e-18" "0"                       
"two.sided" "Wilcoxon rank sum test" "wilcoxon_input[1:23] and
```

Comment: your `wilcoxon_result` is not dependendent on `i` so it will be the same for each iteration therefore "copying" the columns

Comment: @Julian_Hn Although it is not dependent on 'i', does it not make sense to be able to bind the variable name to each 'wilcoxon_result' instance that is created per loop? Should I use unlist to unlist 'wilcoxon_result' first and then bind 'i' using cbind?

Answer (score 0):

Now I've been able to only use one reference - i.e. `i`, so the following now works perfectly:

```
dta <- c()

max_col_A1.1_OR_df_transp <- ncol(A1.1_OR_df_transp)

for(i in colnames(A1.1_OR_df_transp[2:max_col_A1.1_OR_df_transp])){
  wilcoxon_input_CTRL <- A1.1_OR_df_transp_CTRL[1:23,i]
  wilcoxon_input_PATIENT_GROUP <- A1.1_OR_df_transp_PATIENT_GROUP[24:76,i]
  wilcoxon_result <- wilcox.test(wilcoxon_input_CTRL, wilcoxon_input_PATIENT_GROUP, alternative = "two.sided", paired = FALSE, exact = TRUE) 
  dta <- data.frame(unlist(wilcoxon_result),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  dta1 <- t(dta)
  dta1 <- cbind(i,dta1)
  output_frame <- rbind(output_frame, dta1)
}
```